# What's the equivalent to chattr in the rust standard library?

Tags: linux, rust, permissions, fs

I need to execute the equivalent of `chattr +i myfile.txt` in rust.

Since the call for `chmod` is `fs::set_permissions()`
I was expecting something like `fs::set_attributes()` to also exists, but I cannot find it in the docs.

Is there an std function to set (linux) file attributes?

Comment: There are a bunch of `*attr` methods in [`linux::syscall`](https://docs.rs/linux/0.0.1/linux/syscall/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the standard library for this. The `i` attribute, and file attributes in general, are very system specific, and are outside the scope for a portable standard library.

Internally, the `chattr` uses the [`FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` `ioctl`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/man-pages/ioctl_iflags.2.en). You may have to implement code that uses it yourself, using a crate like [nix](https://lib.rs/crates/nix) can help.